# How to execute scala tests programmatically

Tags: scala, testing

I'm looking for a way to execute scala tests (implemented in munit, but it could be also ScalaTest) programmatically. I want to perform more or less what `sbt test` does out-of-the box inside my own scala code, without running `sbt` (focusing on test discovery and execution and getting back a report).

I some something like this in mind:

```scala
object Test extends App {
   val tests = TestDiscovery.discover("package.that.has.tests")
   val reports = tests.foreach(test => test.execute())
   // do something with the reports, maybe print to console
}
```

Is there any documentation related to this?

Comment: take a look to the scalatest doc: https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala Test has [`execute()` and `run()`](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/invoking_execute#:%7E:text=The%20core%20design%20of%20ScalaTest,call%20from%20the%20Scala%20interpreter.).
In order to understand the impact of all the args it's worth looking at the [Scala Test shell as well](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_shell)